# Fatal Error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException'

Tags: php, mysql, fatal-error

I downloaded this website directory and when I ran it, I received the following error:

#### Error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'u471047401_test.Categories' doesn't exist' in /home/u471047401/public_html/inc/blocks/sidebar.php:13 Stack trace: #0 /home/u471047401/public_html/inc/blocks/sidebar.php(13): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 /home/u471047401/public_html/index.php(6): require('/home/u47104740...') #2 {main} thrown in /home/u471047401/public_html/inc/blocks/sidebar.php on line 13

#### Code

```
<?
    $cat = $_GET['cat'];
    if(empty($cat))
    {
        $cat = 0;
    }
    $menu_query = ("
        SELECT cat_id, cat_name, parent_cat
        FROM Categories
        WHERE (cat_id = ? OR parent_cat = ?)");

    $stm = $conn->prepare($menu_query);
    $stm->execute(array($cat, $cat));
    ("u471047401_test.Categories");
    $categories = $stm->fetchAll();
?>

<div class='col-4 col-lg-4 ' style='padding-left:0;'>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked well;">

<?
    foreach($categories as $categories_row)
    {
        $act = $categories_row['cat_id'] == $cat ? 'active' : '';
        echo"
        <li class={$act}>
            <a href='category.php?cat={$categories_row['cat_id']}'>
                {$categories_row['cat_name']}
            </a>
        </li>";

        if($categories_row['cat_id'] == $cat && $categories_row['cat_id'] > 0)
        {
            $back_link = "<li><a href=``'category.php?cat={$categories_row['parent_cat']}' title='Go back to previous category'>Back</a></li>";
        }
    }
?>

<?= $back_link ?>

    </ul>
</div>
```

What is causing this error?

Comment: Delete the single quotation marks which covers the 'FROM'

Answer (score 3):

Remove the quotes around `FROM`

```
SELECT cat_id, cat_name, parent_cat  FROM  Categories
                                    ^----^-----here
```

If you put quotes around it then the DB engine will handle this as a static string and not as a keyword of your query.

Comment: I'm sorry juergen, I'm new to this website, I edited my main question because I've got a new error

Comment: What does this line in your code do? `("u471047401_test.Categories");` It causes the error.

Comment: A few min ago, I always had the error that was something like we can't find u471047401_test.Categories back in line 13 of the .php file, so because I'm totally new to this, I simply added it to that line and the error got away & was replaced by a new one.

Comment: @user3850847: The purpose of this website is to build a knowledge base for programming question. So try to make your posts useful to future visitors too. For instance it would have been better to leave your question as is and ask an new one if you have a new error.

Comment: @user3850847 Then you've got a solution for your first one and now you've got a new one. So please ask a new question, best [a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). juergens perfectly good answer to your original question doesn't make sense with your edited question anymore.

Comment: I'm very sorry that I edited the post.
I can't ask a new question, I need to wait 90 minutes and I need to leave in 15 minutes.. You can view my current error in my edited question.

Comment: @user3850847: Remove that line `("u471047401_test.Categories");` and then see what happens .

Comment: Strange, having the same error after removing that line.

Comment: @user3850847 The execution of your code ends one line above `("u471047401_test.Categories");`. This line can't therefor affect the actual error message, but it is an unnecessary line. Removing this line would be a good idea. And before I forget: please accept the answer of juergen and I will rollback the question to the original one, so your original question will not stay open.